# IFS formula to check two different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create an invoice tracker that has one cell with the options for "Paid", "Past Due" or "Pending".

My formula for the cell is

```
=IFS(C3>=0,"Pending", C3<0,"Past Due")
```

C3 is the number of days that are approaching the due date. I am trying to make the formula return "Paid" if I input a check number into cell G3. What can I do to update this formula to represent the "Paid" status?

Comment: IFS function: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFS-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will return "Paid" if cell G3 is not blank, otherwise it returns "Pending" or "Past Due" based on the number in cell C3.

```
=IFS(G3<>"","Paid",C3>=0,"Pending",C3<0,"Past due")
```